# Pass Param and access Event in JS Event Listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have my canvas which on click alerts the position you clicked.This works fine, but now I want to pass a parameter through to the function domouseDown while also being able to access the event to get the positions on the click (event.pageX). I have successfully passed a parameter to the function by changing the event Listener to function(){doMouseDown(param); } , but then event.pagex and y no longer work. I need to get both but I can only seem to get one or the other to work.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="400"></canvas>
```

JavaScript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", doMouseDown, false);
//Or  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){doMouseDown(param); }, false);

function doMouseDown(event) {
    //or function doMouseDown(event, param){
    var totalOffsetX = 0;
    var totalOffsetY = 0;
    var canvasX = 0;
    var canvasY = 0;
    var currentElement = this;
    do {
        totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
        totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
    }
    while (currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)
    canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
    canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;
    alert("x" + canvasX + " " + "y:" + canvasY);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand, but is this want you need?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", createEventWithParam("MyParam"), false);

function createEventWithParam(param) {
    return function doMouseDown(event){
        var totalOffsetX = 0;
        var totalOffsetY = 0;
        var canvasX = 0;
        var canvasY = 0;
        var currentElement = this;
        do{
            totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
            totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        while(currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)
        canvasX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
        canvasY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;
        alert("x" + canvasX + " " + "y:" + canvasY + " - " + param);
    }
}
```

This is a way to create an event handler with a parameter.

Comment: This doesnt let me access the event.pageX, Y

Comment: Why not? In my example I have access to both pageX and pageY. Try it on _jsfiddle_: [http://jsfiddle.net/fk3r4zyn/](http://jsfiddle.net/fk3r4zyn/)